# How to dinamically change Combo box display member

Tags: database, vb.net, combobox, radio-button

I have a database in my VB program linked to a combo box. When selecting a name from combo box it will then auto fill the other text boxes with the related information. I'm now adding in a radio button to allow the switch of name & address within the combo box allowing the user to search depending on their preferences.

Does someone know a short line of code I could put within my radio button `private sub` which would change the display member of the combo box when selected?

Thanks

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: Change it in same way as it was set in the first place. Or show code how you set it

Comment: at the moment I have my combo box and texts boxes set up without the use of code I simply dragged my access database into VB then simple dragged it from my reference into my application which then made its own textboxes. I have made my radio button and I know what the database and the display members are called just was wondering what I have to put into my If Statement inside of the radio button private sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is example of *how to switch display member*. It is not necessarily makes  design sense but it shows how to do it. This is working code BTW

```
Public Class Vendor
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Address As String    
End Class
 . . . . . 
' Form constructor
Dim listOfVendors As New List(Of Vendor)()
listOfVendors.Add(New Vendor() With {.Address = "A1", .Id = 1, .Name = "Name1"})
listOfVendors.Add(New Vendor() With {.Address = "A2", .Id = 2, .Name = "Name2"})
listOfVendors.Add(New Vendor() With {.Address = "A3", .Id = 3, .Name = "Name3"})

cboVendors.ValueMember = "Id" 
cboVendors.DisplayMember = "Name"
cboVendors.DataSource = listOfVendors 

. . . . .
' Assume SearchOptionChanged is handler for your radio buttons of the same group
Pivate Sub SearchOptionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbSearchbyName.CheckedChanged, rbSearchbyAddress.CheckedChanged

    Dim rb As RadioButton = CType(sender, RadioButton)
    If rb.Name = "rbSearchbyName" AndAlso rb.Checked Then 
        cboVendors.DisplayMember = "Name"
    Else If rb.Name = "rbSearchbyAddress" AndAlso rb.Checked Then 
        cboVendors.DisplayMember = "Address"
    Else
        ' put your logic here
    End If

End Sub

' Getting item
Private Sub FillForm()
    ' Cool thing about this style is, now you can fill text boxes with data
    Dim v As Vendor = TryCast(cboVendors.SelectedItem, Vendor)
    If v Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Vendor selected")
    Else
        txtName.Text = v.Name
        txtAddress.Text = v.Address
        lblId.Text = v.Id
    End If

End Sub
```

This shows how to do it. You need to work out your logic.